# how to Toggle Triggers

Tags: javascript, html

How can I trigger toggles?
I have two toogles and need them to show only one per time.

When click the toggles once, the two containers open one below the other, but I want the first toggle to become inactive or collapse and the second toggle to be active, but at the same place and not one below the other.

e.g.

click "open 1" --> div berlin expands

click "open 2" --> div berlin collapse and div zurich expand

etc...

My HTML:

```
<div class="toggle">
<button  onclick="male()">open 1</button>
<button  onclick="female()">open 2</button>
</div>

<div id="berlin" style="display: none">
Toggle 1 content
</div>


<div id="zurich" style="display: none">
Toggle 2 content
</div>
```

my JS

```
function male() {
  var x = document.getElementById("berlin");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function female() {
  var x = document.getElementById("zurich");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

any ideas or help? 
Thaks in adnvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply hide the `berlin` div on click of `zurich` div by deafult and same you can do for the click on other div like:

```js
function male() {
  var x = document.getElementById("berlin");
  document.getElementById("zurich").style.display = "none";
  x.style.display = x.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

function female() {
  var x = document.getElementById("zurich");
  document.getElementById("berlin").style.display = "none";
  x.style.display = x.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <button onclick="male()">open 1</button>
  <button onclick="female()">open 2</button>
</div>

<div id="berlin" style="display: none">
  Toggle 1 content
</div>

<div id="zurich" style="display: none">
  Toggle 2 content
</div>
```

Comment: yaayyyy, it works just great, thanks a lot for super fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `hidden` attribute, something like:

```js
let x = document.getElementById("berlin");
let y = document.getElementById("zurich");

function male() {
  x.hidden = !x.hidden;
  y.hidden = true;
}

function female() {
  y.hidden = !y.hidden;
  x.hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <button onclick="male()">open 1</button>
  <button onclick="female()">open 2</button>
</div>

<div id="berlin" hidden>
  Toggle 1 content
</div>

<div id="zurich" hidden>
  Toggle 2 content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more toggle button and more containers to show hide, then this should help

```js
const toggleContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-container');

function hideAllToggles() {
  toggleContainers.forEach(toggle => {
    toggle.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}

hideAllToggles();

function showToggle(id) {
  hideAllToggles();
  var x = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
  x.classList.remove('hidden');
  x.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
<button  onclick="showToggle('berlin')">open 1</button>
<button  onclick="showToggle('zurich')">open 2</button>
</div>

<div class="toggle-container" id="berlin">
Toggle 1 content
</div>


<div class="toggle-container" id="zurich">
Toggle 2 content
</div>
```